# Finder cannot navigate to folders inside ~/Documents

Tags: finder

I can *manually* navigate to `~/Documents/untitled folder` in the Finder:

[image]

But if I use "Go to Folder"…

[image]

[image]

Finder cannot navigate to `~/Documents/untitled folder`, and instead falls back to the root of my hard drive:

[image]

Snooping the file syscalls reveals that two file open syscalls were attempted, and that neither encountered any errors:

```
sudo opensnoop 2>/dev/null -ef '/Users/birch/Documents/untitled folder' 
  UID    PID COMM          FD ERR PATH                 
  501  17873 Finder        21   0 /Users/birch/Documents/untitled folder 
  501  17873 Finder        21   0 /Users/birch/Documents/untitled folder
```

I get this exact same behaviour when I try to drag-and-drop a path within `~/Documents` into a file picker dialogue (navigates to `Macintosh HD` instead of the intended filepath).

The space in the filepath is not the problem (I get the same results with simpler filepaths).
The tilde in the filepath is not the problem (I get the same results with paths under `/Users/birch/Documents`).

I can navigate just fine to `~/Documents` itself, but no deeper.
I can navigate just fine to `~/Music/iTunes`; this problem seems to **solely** affect "files under `~/Documents`".

`cd ~/Documents/untitled\ folder` in Terminal works perfectly.

The permissions of `~/Documents` is the same as `~/Downloads`. `~/Downloads` works, yet `~/Documents` doesn't:

```
ls -l ~ | grep -E '(Documents|Music|Downloads)$'
drwx------@  425 birch  staff       13600 25 Aug 09:22 Documents
drwx------@ 1205 birch  staff       38560 19 Sep 14:57 Downloads
drwx------+   11 birch  staff         352 24 Aug  2020 Music
```

`~/Documents` describes "custom access" for "Sharing & Permissions". Could that be significant?

[image]

Closer look at permissions, as requested by @nohillside:

```
ls -ldOe@ ~/Documents
drwx------@ 425 birch  staff  - 13600 25 Aug 09:22 /Users/birch/Documents
    com.apple.macl     72 
 0: group:everyone deny delete

ls -ldOe@ ~/Downloads
drwx------@ 1205 birch  staff  - 38560 19 Sep 17:35 /Users/birch/Downloads
    com.apple.macl     72 
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

I do not sync `~/Documents` with iCloud, nor is it used for Dropbox or OneDrive:

[image]

I am using macOS 11.5.2 Big Sur on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014). I *think* this problem started with Big Sur.

I am using APFS filesystem. `~/Documents` contains 115GB of content, across 421 items.

This is an Administrator account (and I presume is also the system owner).

The problem still reproduces in Safe mode.

Any ideas? Being unable to navigate to folders makes macOS terribly broken for me.

=====

**UPDATE**: I tried a lift-and-shift.
*tl;dr: didn't fix `~/Documents`. but moved my files into a directory which isn't cursed.*

The plan:

1. Copy my documents into a new folder
2. Confirm that the new folder works fine
3. Delete `~/Documents`
4. Rename my new folder to be `~/Documents`

I did the copied all of my documents into a new folder, `~/Docs`:

```
rsync -a ~/Documents/ ~/Docs
```

*Sadly `rsync` doesn't make use of APFS cloning, so took a bit of time and space.*

This new `~/Docs` folder was **not** afflicted by the navigation bug.

Before going as far as to delete `~/Documents`, I decided to do one more check: if I delete all the files inside it, does it recover?
The answer was no (admittedly I deleted via Finder *Select All*, so may have missed something).

Next step was to delete `~/Documents` (don't do this):

```
sudo rm -rf ~/Documents
```

This had very weird results. No error message. But the `~/Documents` folder was still there (in Finder and in the Terminal -- confirmed by `ls` and `stat`).

If you attempted to navigate to this "deleted" `~/Documents` folder (for example with Cmd Shift O): the breadcrumb in the Finder window would just say `Documents` (with no parent folders).

This scuppered my plan to "rename `~/Docs` to become my new `~/Documents` folder". I was likewise disallowed from executing (for example) `mkdir ~/Documents`, on the grounds that such a folder "already existed".

So, lift-and-shift wasn't possible. And I didn't want to use the ghost `~/Documents` whilst it was clearly displaying the wrong absolute filepath in Finder.
I needed to get back to at least having a "no more broken than usual" `~/Documents` folder.

I rebooted, and my `~/Documents` folder was back to "as broken as usual" (i.e. the Finder breadcrumb presented the correct absolute filepath).

I believe the reason it self-repaired is related to some iCloud sync behaviour. Users that have iCloud sync enabled for their Documents folder will find that it is empty (maybe absent?) until a few seconds after login. I do not have iCloud sync enabled, but I suspect some support here tried to enforce that "there should always be a Documents folder".
So, reboot may have been overkill: a logout/login may have sufficed.

Anyway, my `~/Documents` folder is still cursed. To the extent that even deleting it and regenerating it didn't help. Any more ideas?

Alternatively, does anybody know a way to rebind Finder's <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to navigate me to my new `~/Docs` folder?

Comment: I have "custom access as well", nevertheless: Can you run `ls -ldOe@ ~/Documents` and add the result?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @nohillside. I've added the results; looks identical to the working folder `~/Downloads`…

Comment: does `cd ~/Documents/untitled \folder` work as expected in Terminal?

Comment: @KevinGrabher yes, `cd ~/Documents/untitled\ folder` in Terminal works perfectly.

Comment: If you create from the Finder a new folder in ~/Documents, have you the same problem? How did you create these "untitled ..." folders?

Comment: @Jean_JD the problem occurs with every folder under `~/Documents`, even new ones that I create with Cmd Shift N in Finder. these "untitled folder"s aren't a special case; I focused the screenshot on them simply because they contain no personal information.

Comment: Does this also occur if you specify the full, absolute path in Finder’s Go panel? (I.e., `/Users/birch/Documents/untitled folder`)

Comment: @pion yes, the problem reproduces even if I use the absolute path in Finder's Go panel.

Comment: I have the same problem (reported here https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/439597/30895 because I had not seen this thread). Now it seems that the problem occurs only if “Documents” is *not* in the Finder sidebar – can you confirm that?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by adding the `Documents` folder to my sidebar in Finder. (as suggested in https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/444443)

[image: Documents Folder in Finder Sidebar Setting]

Answer (score 0):

I use the answer from, because I can't give the command in comment mode

Can you try this command from terminal to reset user permissions :

```
diskutil resetUserPermissions / `id -u`
```

Comment: I've now done this, but it didn't fix the problem. thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Ok. Can you add the results of the command `ls -ldOe@ ~/Documents/untitled folder`?

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x  3 birch  staff  - 96 19 Sep 15:27 /Users/birch/Documents/untitled folder`

Comment: If you boot in Safe Mode (push shift key at boot) have you the same problem?

Comment: I've just tried Safe Mode -- no improvement, I'm afraid.

Comment: I had this problem and applied this permissions command.  I could see the files existed using `ls` in the terminal.  The permissions did not seem to change much and the Finder was still not working immediately and file-info detected "unknown" permissions.  After a system restart, the permissions were OK again.  I don't know if this command fixed it or the system applied patches on restart.