# `open folder` may fail due to “untranslocated nodes”

Tags: macos, finder, bug

For some reason, opening a folder in the Finder from the command line with

```
open path/to/folder
```

does not work anymore for subdirectories of my Documents folder:

```
% cd
% mkdir Documents/TestDir
% open Documents/TestDir
```

opens a new Finder window, but that does not show the “TestDir” folder but the
“Computer” folder.

The system log shows these error messages about “untranslocated nodes”:

```
% log stream --predicate 'process == "Finder" and messageType == error' 
Filtering the log data using "process == "Finder" AND logType == 16"
Timestamp                       Thread     Type        Activity             PID    TTL  
2022-04-10 14:07:42.994683+0200 0xb6f5     Error       0x0                  444    0    Finder: (LaunchServices) [com.apple.launchservices:default] capability properties: could not find untranslocated node for <FSNode 0x6000035b9aa0> { isDir = ?, path = <private> }, proceeding on the assumption it is not translocated: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"
2022-04-10 14:07:42.994777+0200 0xb6f5     Error       0x0                  444    0    Finder: (LaunchServices) [com.apple.launchservices:default] capability properties: could not find untranslocated node for <FSNode 0x6000035b9aa0> { isDir = ?, path = <private> }, proceeding on the assumption it is not translocated: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"
2022-04-10 14:07:43.003949+0200 0xb6f5     Error       0x0                  444    0    Finder: (LaunchServices) [com.apple.launchservices:default] capability properties: could not find untranslocated node for <FSNode 0x60000358d0c0> { isDir = ?, path = <private> }, proceeding on the assumption it is not translocated: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"
2022-04-10 14:07:43.004319+0200 0xb6f5     Error       0x0                  444    0    Finder: (LaunchServices) [com.apple.launchservices:default] capability properties: could not find untranslocated node for <FSNode 0x60000358d0c0> { isDir = ?, path = <private> }, proceeding on the assumption it is not translocated: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"
```

Running First Aid on Macintosh HD (in Recovery mode) did not report any errors.

The problem occurs only with (nested) subdirectories of “Documents”. Opening
“Documents” itself or any other folder works correctly.

Sometimes it works if I specify the "-R" flag explicitly, e.g.

```
% open -R Documents/TestDir
```

but not always.

My configuration: macOS 12.3.1 on a MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2020).

Any ideas how to fix (or further investigate) this problem are welcome.

Comment: It looks like the same (unsolved) problem reported here: [Finder cannot navigate to folders inside ~/Documents](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/427570/30895) – I had not noticed that when posting this question.

Comment: I can confirm what you said in other thread. Problem happens when Documents is NOT in the sidebar.  macOS 12.3.1. That might be a bug.

Comment: @Gilby: Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Weird.  I don't get the same problem for Downloads or Desktop which, like Documents, are a bit special.  Surprised this has not been highlighted before as it applies to both `open` and Finder's `Go to Folder`. I will do a Feedback to Apple.

Comment: @Gilby: Yes, only Documents is affected, nothing else, as far as I can see.

Comment: Feedback to Apple: FB9984585

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug in macOS 12.3.1, but apparently it happens only if the “Documents” folder is *not* shown in the Finder sidebar.

So there is a workaround: Make sure that the “Documents” folder is selected in the “Sidebar” tab of the Finder preferences:

[image]

Comment: Other answers (perhaps providing more insight on the problem) are welcome, of course.