# `open` is not functioning for ~/Documents/*

Tags: terminal, finder

On my main account on my main Mac, the `open` command is not functioning only for the sub directories under `~/Documents/`. Namely, `open ~/Documents/test` does not open that directory in Finder.app, but instead `~/` is shown in Finder.

I have been using the command for many years but I have never seen this issue.

What I tried are

1. Removing the `~/Documents` directory but the new `~/Documents` which macOS automatically creates has the same issue.
2. Tried another account and found that it worked. So the problem happens for the main user only.
3. Rebooting does not help.
4. Relaunching Finder does not help.
5. Changing the shell to `bash` or `tcsh` does not help. (I usually use `zsh`.)
6. Opening other sub directories in `~/Library` or `~/Music` works perfect.
7. Checking/unchecking "Terminal.app" in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy Full Disk Access **(update 1)**
8. `Cmd + Shift + G` in Finder cannot change the location to any subdirectories in `~/Documents`. **(update 2)**

In addition, probably the same (unknown) reason causes another issue.

Any application dialogs like "Open" or "Save" cannot accept drag & drop for sub directories under `~/Documents`. Namely, if I want to save a text file from TextEdit and drag & drop `~/Documents/test` in the save dialog, this location is not selected but instead `~/` is shown.

Does anyone have a nice idea to resolve or debug this issue?

---

**(update 3)**

Probably due to the facts that I forced to remove `~/Documents` by using `sudo` and that Finder recreated a new directory, the xattr of `~/Documents` looks to be not properly set. How do I restore the settings? (`XXX` is my user name)

```
$ ls -led Library Music Desktop Movies Documents
drwx------@ 451 XXX  staff  14432 Jul 20 19:36 Desktop
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x    2 XXX  staff     64 Jul 23 11:09 Documents
drwx------@ 132 XXX  staff   4224 May  8 14:52 Library
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  31 XXX  staff    992 Feb 26  2020 Movies
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+   8 XXX  staff    256 Mar 14  2020 Music
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

The new directory contains `GarageBand`, `iMovie`, `Keynote`, ... `TextEdit` that are graphically shown in Finder, but they do not exist when executing `ls` in Terminal.

```
$ ls -a Documents
.  ..
```

`~/Desktop/GarageBand` is a link(?) to `/Users/XXX/Library/Containers/com.apple.garageband10/Data`.

---

**(update 4)**

I found that

```
$ open ~/Documents/test
```

was not functioning (i.e., `~` is shown in Finder), but

```
$ sudo mv ~/Documents ~/Documents_org
$ open ~/Documents_org/test
```

did work.

So the issue looks to be caused by the special directory settings of macOS (12.4) and my broken `~/Documents`.

---

**(update 5)**

- My main account

```
$ mdls Documents
kMDItemContentType             = ""
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate     = (null)
kMDItemFSCreationDate          = (null)
kMDItemFSCreatorCode           = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags           = (null)
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon         = (null)
kMDItemFSInvisible             = 0
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden     = (null)
kMDItemFSIsStationery          = (null)
kMDItemFSLabel                 = (null)
kMDItemFSName                  = (null)
kMDItemFSNodeCount             = (null)
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID          = (null)
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID           = (null)
kMDItemFSSize                  = (null)
kMDItemFSTypeCode              = ""
kMDItemInterestingDate_Ranking = 2022-07-23 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemLastUsedDate            = 2022-07-23 03:01:10 +0000
kMDItemLastUsedDate_Ranking    = 2022-07-23 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemUseCount                = 2
kMDItemUsedDates               = (
    "2022-07-22 15:00:00 +0000"
)
```

- Another account

```
% mdls Documents 
_kMDItemDisplayNameWithExtensions      = "Documents"
kMDItemAlternateNames                  = (
    Documents
)
kMDItemContentCreationDate             = 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemContentCreationDate_Ranking     = 
kMDItemContentModificationDate         = 2021-04-12 07:57:09 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate_Ranking = 2021-04-12 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemContentType                     = "public.folder"
kMDItemContentTypeTree                 = (
    "public.folder",
    "public.directory",
    "public.item"
)
kMDItemDateAdded                       = 2021-03-31 16:24:18 +0000
kMDItemDateAdded_Ranking               = 2021-03-31 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemDisplayName                     = "Documents"
kMDItemDocumentIdentifier              = 0
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate             = 2021-04-12 07:57:09 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate                  = 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode                   = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags                   = 0
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon                 = (null)
kMDItemFSInvisible                     = 0
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden             = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery                  = (null)
kMDItemFSLabel                         = 0
kMDItemFSName                          = "Documents"
kMDItemFSNodeCount                     = 1
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID                  = 20
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID                   = 502
kMDItemFSSize                          = (null)
kMDItemFSTypeCode                      = ""
kMDItemInterestingDate_Ranking         = 2021-04-12 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemKind                            = "Folder"
```

Comment: Does Terminal have Full Disk Access (or at least access to Documents) in the Security&Privacy preference pane?

Comment: Thank you for the remind. I forgot to add it in the list above. Yes, I checked it and repeated unchecking and checking, but it did not help.

Comment: The original question updated.

Comment: Which access rights and ACLs are set on Documents?

Comment: That's a good point. I did not check it. I updated the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading a "Related" post below, I found a solution to restore the Documents folder setting.

[Spotlight can't open a folder inside ~/Documents/](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/413545/spotlight-cant-open-a-folder-inside-documents)

The solution is

1. Make new temporally directories `~/Documents_org` and `~/Desktop_org` and move the contents of `~/Documents` and `~/Desktop` into them.
2. Enable iCloud Drive sync for "Desktop & Documents Folders" in System Preferences and wait for the sync to be finished.
3. Disable the iCloud Drive sync.
4. Move back the `~/Documents_org` and `~/Desktop_org` contents to the original dilectroies.